# Android 11 ADB change preferred network mode

Tags: adb, root-access, android-11

**Situation**

I am trying to change the preferred network mode of two Android devices using ADB through the following commands.
Both phones run Android 11 API 30 and **are rooted**.
The entries in question were determined through `settings_global.xml` while change it manually via the UI.
The modes in question can be found here: [cs.android.com](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:packages/services/Telephony/src/com/android/phone/settings/RadioInfo.java;l=129;drc=de40a3f44e01829e821bebb49047b4332c176b9b).

I want it to run via ADB.

**Device Input**

Here for the first device:

```
adb shell settings put global preferred_network_mode 32,20 
adb shell settings put global preferred_network_mode19 32
adb shell stop ril-daemon
adb shell start ril-daemon
adb shell settings put global airplane_mode_on 1 
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE --ez state true 
adb shell settings put global airplane_mode_on 0 
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE --ez state false
```

This works out fine. I can control the RAT Technology as intended.
Here for the second device:

```
adb shell settings put global preferred_network_mode 32
adb shell settings put global preferred_network_mode11 32 
adb shell stop ril-daemon 
adb shell start ril-daemon 
adb shell settings put global airplane_mode_on 1 
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE --ez state true 
adb shell settings put global airplane_mode_on 0 
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE --ez state false
```

The entries do show up if called by using `adb shell settings list global`, in the `settings_global.xml` and also in the UI but the modem is just not bothered by this.

**Questions**

1. Why are there that many different preferred_network_mode entries (up to twenty) and in what do they differ?
2. Is there a way to force a re-read of settings_global.xml (after it was adjusted) or the global settings?
3. Do I need to change the procedure for the latter phone? (different action call?) If so, to what?